How to model realistic soccer goal net?
Please can anyone advice on how to make a realistic goal net like so:
https://sketchfab.com/3d-models/football-goal-bf20be6e423e41d191134ab77c590992
(I need to make squares, rather than the honeycomb from the model)
Currently, I have made a wireframe mesh, with bevel and shade smooth, but I can't figure out a way to make joint knots, or a right material/ UV for rope pattern.

I have also tried planes (cube with front and bottom face removed. Using a net material with alpha, from blenderkit, trying various UV scaling values, I cannot get a good line up of the net. Plus not sure how to add the support rope too.

Any pointers would be much appreciated, thanks.

there are nets with knots and without knots. The linked sketchfab example has no knots. What's wrong with your wireframe version?

That alpha material method looks okay to me, you would just need to adjust the UVs to get them to line up, which should be pretty straighforward,

Maybe related: How can I keep those stripes together? - maybe; I don't know if any technique there is needed here.

You can do this with a Cloth simulation to get the shape of the stretched net, and either with a modeled mesh or a transparent image texture as you did.
The modeled soccer net looks better in close-ups and from certain camera angles. On the other hand, the transparent image textures look rather flat from these angles in close-ups, but you need much less geometry.
Cloth Physics

model the net as a plane (Deform Cage in the example)
create a vertex group to pin the edges of the front and the bottom. Add the vertices to this group (e.g. pin)
extrude the vertices of the upper corners at the back left and right, and add these 2 vertices to the pin group

add a Cloth simulation
choose the Silk preset (1)
enter the pin group, enable [X] Sewing to pull the back left and right holding strings (the extruded verts), define the Maximum Sewing Force (e.g. 8.0), and increase Shrinking (0.110) to simulate stretching (2)
then run the simuation (3) and it should look like this:


Now you can texture it and you're done. Or you model the net meshes and use the "cage" with the Surface Deform modifier to deform the soccer net geometry.
Soccer Net Meshes + Surface Deform modifier

get an image of a net mesh and add it as an image plane

use the knife tool (K) in Edit mode to cut the image


add 2 Array modifiers with the [X] Merge option enabled to create a mesh plane

make it seamless by cutting and moving the strings


add a Solidify modifier and perhaps a Subdivision Surface modifier to smooth the mesh and fix the texture in the UV editor

align the meshes to the cage and add some rope parts at the edges (not done in the example). Finally, bind it with a Surface Deform modifier to the Deformation Cage




Hi,Thanks for this @Blunder. I was going to look at cloth deform at the end. The main thing I guess I was stuck on was the support ropes that run along the net edges. How can I create them and correctly map UVs. Thanks
